# How the external authentication handled in WSO2 APIM for an external/Third Party APIs

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 APIM (2.5.0) and IS (5.6.0). They both are integrated and working well.

Now, if I onboard an third party API in API Management and using oauth token I can be able to access it. But question is how to handle any external or third party APIs which has its own authentication.

SO basically, using WSO2 APIM token I can be able to access the onboarded API to use but we will not be able to get any response as the onboarded API has its own authentication (basic or oauth).

How to achieve this in APIM.

Any help or guidance will be helpful.

EDIT:
Here is the sequence I am using (Thanks Bee for the guidance)

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="backend-token-sequence">
<property name="inputmessage" expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/Login/msg/inputmessage.json')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

               <script language="js">
               var payload = mc.getProperty("inputmessage");  
               mc.setPayloadJSON(payload)
               </script>
               <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
               <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING" description="messageType"/>
               <property name="temp" expression="$axis2:REST_URL_POSTFIX"/>
               <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>
               <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>

<call blocking="true">
    <endpoint>
         <http uri-template="https://xx.com/auth/login" method="POST" />
    </endpoint>
</call>
<property name="x-access-token" scope="transport" expression="json-eval($.token)"/>
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" expression="$ctx:temp"/>

</sequence>
```

This is the inflow sequence which is being used to one of API. 
I am calling API using APIM URL with GET Method, passing APIM bearer token

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 APIM out of the box supports [basic auth](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Basic+Auth) and [digest auth](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Digest+Auth) as backend security schemas.

In addition to that, using [custom sequences](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+Mediation+Extensions#AddingMediationExtensions-CreatinganduploadingmanuallyintheAPIPublisher) you can pass any kind of security token to the backend.

For backends with OAuth, you have 2 options.

**(1)** Send backend token as well in the API request (inbound to APIM) and then forward it to the backend.

**(2)** Use a custom sequence to call the external token API and take a new token for the backend and then forward it to the backend.

```
<property name="temp" expression="$axis2:REST_URL_POSTFIX"/>
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>
<call blocking="true">
    <endpoint>
         <http uri-template="https://external_idp.com/token" method="GET" />
    </endpoint>
</call>
<property name="BackendAuthHeader" scope="transport" expression="json-eval($.tokenresponse.token)"/>
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" expression="$ctx:temp"/>
```

I recommend **(1)** due to its simplicity.

**Edit:** More about option **(1)**:

If your backend expects a header something other than "Authorization" header you can simply send that header with your requests and it will be sent to the backend.

However, if your backend also expects the "Authorization" header, then it becomes a conflict as you can't use the same header to pass 2 tokens (1 for GW and 1 for backend). To solve that problem, you can use the [custom authorization header for gateway](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Securing+APIs#SecuringAPIs-PerAPIcustomization) feature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was working on the same and could apply option1. But, also I have requirement where the step2 fits more appropriately. Can you share some samples or documentation which could help me to achieve that

Comment: All these link[https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Pass+a+Custom+Authorization+Token+to+the+Backend] leads to the point where in the request itself must have two headers (1 for APIGW and 2 for backend). Instead, I want that request must have 1 header (for APIGW) and using sequence, I can call the backend tokenendpoint and get the token and place in the header. Hope that I am clear to what I want exactly to achieve. Please let me know if you have anything which would be helpful to me or let me know if question is not clear.

Comment: Added a sample to call and external token API, and read and set backend token.

Comment: Taking your response as reference, I have created one sequence and attached to the API for backend API token. I am making POST request to get the token from backend and passing the same to the property mediator as it was shown by you. Now, I am calling get method to use the API (internally, it should make post request to the Token URL and get back the token) and then the header will be set as it should be. But, for some reason the backend POST request is appended by the actual get request URI.. not sure why... any help pls

Comment: I made a few changes to the sample. Try that out. (note: I didn't try myself.)

Comment: Thanks but it does not seems to be working.. Should I share the API and sequence here.

Comment: I think now I am able to get to the post request and get the token for backend api and setting up in the property mediator to be used. Only issue now I am facing is providing the REST_URL_POSTFIX as I am getting error in sender error as the URI is not getting attached later which is the actual URI of an API

Comment: I got this working now. I was using header mediator while posting to the token URL and that was causing error while the actual URL of API was invoked. Removed the header mediator and it worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: All you needed was some time... :)