# How to call/configure a secured API in WSo2 API manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I need to configure a set of apis which are secured and uses client credentials and password alone with client key and secret key. 
And how to track the users that are trying to access the API.

I tried by adding proxy mediators.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the API which you will create in WSO2 API Manager will have secure feature. 
You can secure the APIs with 
oauth which comes inbuilt in the application or
you can integrate the WSO2 Identity Server to be used as Identity Provider for WSO2 APIM.
Below link will show how to create and publish APIs in APIM Manager.
[https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Create+and+Publish+an+API]

Once you are able to invoke the created API, you can check the usage of that API by checking on the Analytics profile for it. You can have it integrated with the API Manager.
Below link is useful to setup Analytics profile for APIM 2.5.0
[https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Configuring+APIM+Analytics/]

Once the Analytics is setup for APIM, you can use the DB to fetch the usage of the APIs.

Comment: No my question is not about securing a API. We can configure a API in API Manager and make it secure, but I want to configure an API which is already secured. In the request i need to pass user credentials may be as a header and get it authenticated.

Comment: Ok, so to understand your question. In the API which you have already created must have backend server which is secured.. is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes correct. the API in backend server is secured. basically some mediator or any other way to use when we do configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your query, this is how you should proceed.

You can add a custom sequence in the inflow of the API ( you can do that from API Publisher only by editing it) [https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+Mediation+Extensions]

Sequence Code will be like below:

```
    <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="custom-sequence_name">

    <property xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                name="accesstoken"
                value="put your token here"
                scope="transport"
                type="STRING"/>
    </sequence>
```

This above one is for token for backend which is static. For dynamic token you can create a sequence accordingly.

This should solve your query :)

For dynamic, go here [[How the external authentication handled in WSO2 APIM for an external/Third Party APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955337/how-the-external-authentication-handled-in-wso2-apim-for-an-external-third-party/55956008?noredirect=1#comment99144031_55956008])

Comment: Can you give me an example for Dynamic

Answer (score 0):

If your backend is oauth secured then you can use one of the following methods

1. Method-1

OAuth mediator which can be used for generating OAuth 2.0 tokens and for calling the backends that are secured with OAuth 2.0 protocol. Refer [this](https://github.com/npamudika/wso2-oauth-mediator).

2. Method-2

writing a mediation sequence which generates an access token for the backend and making a connection to the OAuth 2.0 secured backend.Refer [this](https://medium.com/@menakajayawardena/wso2-how-to-using-oauth2-protected-back-ends-with-api-manager-5d7e234c61c) blog.